# New to flask and Flask-Login - ImportError: No module named login

Tags: python, flask

It appears that installation of flask-login has issues.  Despite a successful install using the below

```
 pip install flask-login
```

My app.py file:

```
 from flaskext.login import LoginManager
 lm = LoginManager()
```

I get this error :

```
ImportError: No module named login
```

So how do I resolve

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There was a transition of the flask extension import way:

> Instead we now recommend naming packages `flask_foo` instead of the now deprecated `flaskext.foo`. Flask 0.8 introduces a redirect import system that lets uses import from `flask.ext.foo` and it will try `flask_foo` first and if that fails `flaskext.foo`.
>
> Flask extensions should urge users to **import** from **`flask.ext.foo`** instead of flask_foo or flaskext_foo so that extensions can transition to the new package name without affecting users. ([Source](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/extensiondev/#extension-import-transition))

Use this import way with Flask 0.8 or later:

```
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
```

Comment: Just a note, if you want to follow Google's import style guide (http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html) you'll need to do your import using the underscored name, like "import flask_login".

Comment: @skyler that was the only import style that worked for me (and Google was pretty scant on results otherwise). Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For flask-login 0.3.2 and later, following is the way:

```
from flask_login import LoginManager
```

to find the flask-login version, you can run the following command in terminal. Just change the name to know the version of other packages.

```
pip show flask-login
```

Note:- not sure from which version of flask-login this convention is followed

Answer (score 2):

There was *yet another* transition of the way Flask extensions are imported.

The Flask 0.8 style `from flask.ext.login import …` is no longer supported, and the even earlier style `from flaskext.login import …` is also no longer supported.

Use this way with Flask 1.0 or later:

```
from flask_login import LoginManager
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for importing LoginManager

from flask_login import LoginManager

Login = LoginManager()

Flask login tutorial
https://learnpyjs.blogspot.com/2021/02/how-to-setup-user-login-in-flask.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

If you have flask (and flask_login) installed already and getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_login'`

**just do**

```
sudo pip install flask
```

or for python3 `sudo pip3 install flask`

**Adding `sudo` solved this issue for me**

Answer (score -5):

```
sudo pip install Flask-Security
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?