# Flask: ImportError: No module named flask.ext.login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am new to flask and I am trying to use flask-login to manage user authentication in my application along with Google plus sign in. I using flask.ext.login in my application but it shows me

ImportError: No Module named flask.ext.login

Here is my views.py file

```
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.runtime.apiproxy_errors import CapabilityDisabledError


from flask import request, render_template, flash, url_for, redirect
from flask.ext.login import current_user
import flask,flask.views
from flask_cache import Cache

from application import app
from decorators import login_required, admin_required
from forms import ExampleForm
from models import ExampleModel

class View(flask.views.MethodView):
    def get(self):
        # check if the user is logged in or not
        if not login.current_user.is_authenticated():
            return app.login_manager.unauthorized()
        return flask.render_template('index.html')




class Login(flask.views.MethodView):
    def get(self):
        return None

    def post(self):
        # Create a state token to prevent request forgery.
        # Store it in the session for later validation.
        state = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
              for x in xrange(32))
        session['state'] = state
        # Set the Client ID, Token State, and Application Name in the HTML while
        # serving it.
        response = make_response(render_template('index.html',CLIENT_ID='1075048200759- 5hunu03e087bha87d48874veh1rvr97f.apps.googleusercontent.com', STATE=state, APPLICATION_NAME='uscore_signin'))
        response.headers['Content-Type']='text/html'
        return response, session
```

Could you please suggest me How to fix it , am I using the importing hierarchy in the wrong way even I followed the previous discussion 
[New to flask and Flask-Login - ImportError: No module named login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751972/new-to-flask-and-flask-login-importerror-no-module-named-login)

Comment: silly question but you have installed flask-login extension, right ?

Comment: yes I have installed that

Comment: Hi Chitrank. Can you please tell us what version of Flask login you are using?

Comment: Hello Joe , I am using Flask-Login - 0.2.7

Comment: can you import ``flask_login``? I don't know how "weird" GAE really is, but i've heard you need to write a lot of custom code for it... could be that ``flask.ext`` is not working properly there.

Comment: Markus I have made one 'lib' folder inside my GAE project and included login.py in lib/flask/ext and it works fine thanks

Comment: I was having the same problem. I have flask-login installed, but was importing flask-login like this    'import flask.ext.login as flask_login' . When I had that followed up with 'from flask.ext.login import current_user' , it failed, same error. When I placed this line before importing flask_login, it worked. 'from flask_login import current_user'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If following does not work:

```
from flask.ext.login import current_user
```

try the following:

```
from flask_login import current_user
```

This is the new convention.

To find the flask-login version, you can run the following command in terminal. Just change the name to know the version of other packages.

```
pip show flask-login
```