# Flask heroku noModuleNamed 'flask_login'

Tags: python, heroku, flask-login

I have a problem when i try to push my flask app to heroku

the error is this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_login'
```

Please help!

Comment: can you provide more detail like how you are importing flask_login what's your flask's version locally and on heroku

Comment: ok i import it like this:  `from flask_login import LoginManager ` and my flask version is 1.1.2

Comment: try `from flask.ext.login import LoginManager` for version Flask 0.8 or later [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751972/new-to-flask-and-flask-login-importerror-no-module-named-login)

Comment: unfortunately it cant find the module`flask.ext`

Comment: Is `flask_login` installed in your heroku server?

Comment: i should see that in `requirements.txt` ?

Comment: Yes, it should be there

Comment: It's not, how can install it?

Comment: On your local env., is it installed? Do you face same issue?

Comment: i don't know how to see that in my env file but it works on localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is telling you that `flask_login` exists in your local development environment, and you still didn't yet add it to your `requirement.txt` before pushing to your heroku app.

You will need to regenerate your `requirement.txt` with :

```
$pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then push your changes and re-install your packages using the new `requirement.txt` file:

```
$pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: great man thank you!!, i appreciate your patience!